# Font similar to San Francisco for PC?

Tags: font-recommendation, apple

I am creating designs for an app as part of my uni work. I have Windows and because I have Windows I am unable to get the San Francisco font as it's only available on Mac.

What is the best font on Photoshop that looks similar as the San Francisco Font?

Answer (score 2):

Google fonts has a nice, free alternative that's close called [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can [download San Francisco](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/) directly from Apple in OTF format. Windows doesn't like that format, but you can use [this tool](https://onlinefontconverter.com/) to convert it to TTF. It worked for me using Windows 10.

I discovered the tool from [this post](https://superuser.com/a/122037/234790) by [Stefan](https://superuser.com/users/31730/stefan).

Comment: Nice, was looking for a similar tool. Do you know if it dumps small caps and other features though?

Comment: Might just want to double check the Apple license agreement to make sure converting is ok and if you can still use the font if you're app isn't for the App Store marketplace.  I know when this font was first released it was strictly proprietary to Apple products.  Just to be safe.